# esc последовательности через cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, esc

Здравствуйте.
как сделать переход на следующую строку за счёт кода

```
echo(первая строка{следующая строка>text.txt
```

знаем что существует двойная >>, или встраиваемые в цмд редакторы. Но интересует именно способ **через echo одной записью.** и естественно по логике, подумал об эскейп последовательности:

```
echo(первая строка{\nвторая строка{
```

но так как понимаю что должно быть экранирование символа, для примера:

```
echo(первая строка{^\nвторая строка{
```

тем не менее это не помогло, подскажите, возможно Я хочу совместить несовместимое?

Comment: Вы выполняете скрипт в Windows или Linux?

Comment: извините забыл, windows 10

Comment: @excellproj, по идее [tag:cmd] - это windows, а [tag:bash] - linux.

Comment: @Qwertiy я знаю, но как видим в вопросе cmd+bash=win10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вот пример для bat-файла, взятый с английского [форума](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files).

   ```
   set NLM=^
   set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
   @echo First Line%NL%Second Line>text.txt
   ```

   После знака "символ вставки" в строке  `set NLM=^` ничего не должно быть. После указанной строки объявления переменной идут **две** пустые строки.
2. И, в принципе, можно было бы проще сделать в одну строку, изменив исполнение очередью **нескольких** команд.

   ```
   @echo First line>text.txt&@echo Second line>>text.txt
   ```